# How to get MySQL connection information in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get connection information of MySQL connection. I am talking about the information we get when we execute the `\s` command in MySQL console.

I want to get this information in Laravel. I've defined my connection and I tried to get this info using `DB::statement('\s');` and  `DB::raw('\s');` in tinker but It's not working.

I also checked Laravel's documentation, but it does not include how to get connection information or MySQL information using Laravel's `DB` class or something that is native in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` is a command for MySQL clients, not a query.  It might be best to figure out a query that gives you what you're looking for, but if you're developing this for multiple environments, you really shouldn't depend on something only available to MySQL.  That defeats the purpose of the database abstraction that Laravel provides.

The DB class is a facade for [DatabaseManager](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.html).  DB::connection() is probably the closest you will find which will return an instance of [MysqlConnection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.html) when using a mysql database and has methods to get information about the connection and access to the underlying PDO object.